# Facebook javascript SDK not loading and giving FB not defined error

Tags: javascript, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using following code to share website page URL on facebook but getting FB not defined error. I checked network window of browser and found it's js file isn't loading and giving "Internal Redirect" error.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '5394xxxxxxxxxx',
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v3.1'
    });
};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function shareFunction(itemId) {
    console.log(itemId);
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        mobile_iframe: true,
        href: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>item/' + itemId,
    }, function (response) {
    });
}
```

"https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" this URL isn't working. I'm working on localhost.